# Sort attributes in category edit page

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, adminhtml, category-attribute

I've added a custom attribute for all the categories. It's currently positioned as the first element in the list when you configure a category. How would I go about about changing it's position in the list? I've tried using the position key in the setup script, but alas no luck. It does get saved in the database, other than that it has no (visual) effect.

setup script:

```
<?php
/** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup $installer */
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'custom_menu', array(
    'type'     => 'int',
    'input'    => 'select',
    'source'   => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
    'global'   => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'required' => false,
    'label'    => 'Is Custom',
    'default'  => 0,
    'group' => 'Menu',
    'position' => 100
));

$installer->endSetup();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `sort_order` instead of `position`.

**Edit:**

Tested on 1.9.3.1 and `sort_order` works ... please check the other attributes position and adjust (increase) `sort_order` value.

If you want do this from DB ...

```
UPDATE `eav_entity_attribute` set `sort_order` = XYZ where `attribute_id` = XYZ
```

Get current sort order via ...

```
SELECT eav.attribute_id, eav.attribute_code, att.sort_order
FROM eav_entity_attribute AS att
LEFT JOIN eav_attribute AS eav ON (eav.attribute_id = att.attribute_id)
LEFT JOIN eav_attribute_group AS grp ON (grp.attribute_group_id = att.attribute_group_id)
WHERE grp.attribute_group_name = 'Menu'
ORDER BY att.sort_order ASC
```

Comment: Alas, same result. It gets saved in the database. No changes on the adminhtml page. I've cleared the cashes with magerun and restarted varnish to be sure.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Hero. That worked! sort_order wan't high enough.